# How do I click an li inside a ul using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

```js
public void testHolidayLink() {

 // login
  driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MCPH_MainLogin_UserNameTextBox")).sendKeys("username");
  driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MCPH_MainLogin_PasswordTextBox")).sendKeys("password");
  driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MCPH_MainLogin_LoginButton")).click();
// click book holiday
  
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='AddInMyQuickLinks']/div/span/ul/li[1]/h3/a")).click();
}
```

I'm trying to click an li inside a ul using xpath, im trying to use this

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='indent'/ul/li[1]a")).click();`

but it can't seem to find the element

```html
<div class="AddIn  atScreens AddInViewportDESKTOP">
  <div style="width:100%;" data-role="collapsible" class="AddInCollapsible ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" id="AddInMyQuickLinks" role="tablist">
    <h2 class="AddinTitleBar ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top ui-accordion-icons" role="tab" id="ui-accordion-AddInMyQuickLinks-header-0" aria-controls="ui-accordion-AddInMyQuickLinks-panel-0"
    aria-selected="true" tabindex="0"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>My Quick Links</h2>
    <div class="AddInMain ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" style="display: block;" id="ui-accordion-AddInMyQuickLinks-panel-0" aria-labelledby="ui-accordion-AddInMyQuickLinks-header-0"
    role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
      <span><ul class="NoIndent"><li class="NoBullet jms-bullet"><h3><a href="javascript:ShowSelectedAddInScreen('-1','32f3c56c-5660-488c-b348-07552ea7d299','0','false',false,'false',true, 'Update Personal Details','e1ff7f13-59fe-4bfc-842d-64a33b0dd98f','b0ab7c0f-bd9d-4f0d-9d1e-508b414ab9ec');"><img alt="Update My Details" src="..\Images\hr.png">Update My Details <span title="Keep your personal information up to date" class="AddInItemDescription">Keep your personal information up to date </span>
      </a>
      </h3>
      </li>
      <li class="NoBullet jms-bullet">
        <h3><a href="javascript:ShowSelectedAddInScreen('-1','8142758e-269a-41f0-b551-433e56dd1225','0','false',false,'false',true, 'Submit a Holiday','e1ff7f13-59fe-4bfc-842d-64a33b0dd98f','4c1ea925-69e5-4950-aeae-18e8493fefd1');"><img alt="Book a Holiday" src="../Style Sheets/images/Holiday114.png">Book a Holiday <span title="Place a request for a holiday" class="AddInItemDescription">Place a request for a holiday </span></a></h3>
      </li>
      <li class="NoBullet jms-bullet">
        <h3><a href="javascript:ShowSelectedAddInScreen('D4292FDC-7213-464C-9C96-019BD67C12DA','bebbb0b6-5328-4737-9709-f389f065db8b','0','false',false,'false',false, 'Employee Mobility','e1ff7f13-59fe-4bfc-842d-64a33b0dd98f','');"><img alt="My Mobility" src="..\Images\hr.png">My Mobility <span title="Places where I would work" class="AddInItemDescription">Places where I would work </span></a></h3>
      </li>
      </ul>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the full xpath

`/html/body/form[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/div/div/span/ul/li[2]/h3/a`

The div has an id which I think i can use to get to the li inside the span but I have no idea how. Apologies if I have not provided the information correctly its my first time posting so please do leave feedback in how I can structure my questions better so as to make it easier for people.

Comment: please give the indentation of ur html file properly

Comment: it will be helpful if u give the full html with proper indentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to click on the first link, meaning

```
 update My details
```

then use this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li:nth-child(1).NoBullet.jms-bullet> h3>a[href^='javascript:ShowSelectedAddInScreen']")).click();
```

If you want to click on the second link, meaning

```
 Book a Holiday
```

then use this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li:nth-child(2).NoBullet.jms-bullet> h3>a[href^='javascript:ShowSelectedAddInScreen']")).click();
```

If you want to click on the third link, then use this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li:nth-child(3).NoBullet.jms-bullet> h3>a[href^='javascript:ShowSelectedAddInScreen']")).click();
```

This can be simplified by using the below code:

```
//first create a web element list which contains all elements inside a list:

List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.NoIndent>li.NoBullet.jms-bullet> h3>a"));

//Now you can select individual elements from a list using:

 elems.get(0).click();//for the 1st element
 elems.get(1).click();//for the 2nd element
 elems.get(2).click();//for the 3rd element
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I've tried what you suggested and I get the following org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == a[href^='javascript:ShowSelectedAddInScreen'] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 305 milliseconds

Comment: It does look like "javascript:ShowSelectedAddInScreen" is not unique in my html which might be why this didnt work

Comment: ok first question is u want to clik on that <a href="javascript:ShowSelectedAddInScreen and second question is in that href the last part "aeae-18e8493fefd1" is unique or not? just search in ur html and let me know

Comment: Yes that is what I want to click. And aeae-18e8493fefd1 is showing in two places one is for the book a holiday link and then it seems to be used again in another page to submit a holiday.

Comment: so, please upload the html ...with out this we can not give u the proper selector.

Comment: Eh how do I do this? Sorry never really used this site before...I take it I dont just copy it from Firebug?

Comment: just give the root of this a href in html

Comment: Hi, added it to the main question. Let me know if that's what you're looking for

Comment: thanks for ur new given html portion and i update my code. it works on my machine and hope on you also.

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay. Yes just tried it and it didn't work I got the following message org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == li:nth-child(2).NoBullet.jms-bullet> h3>a[href^='javascript:ShowSelectedAddInScreen'] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: can u please give me the link?

Comment: Its an internal link I wont be able to share it with you

Comment: any ideas on how I can get this working? Really appreciate your help so far.

Comment: actually i run the code snippet in my machine and than get the css path from there...in my machine it works fine....i think in ur machine the css path is shown differently

Comment: How is that possible? Is there anything i can do to resolve this? I've tried everything i can think off

Comment: can u confirm me one  thing in ur machine .....  <h3><a is shown in one line or a is shown under h3 in <li class="NoBullet jms-bullet">
        <h3><a

Comment: i mean a is shown under h3 or h3 and a both r in same line?

Comment: create chat session here

Comment: open ur url in chrome browser, right click and from there select inspect option......than a window will open below with ur page html source...there click and press cntrl>F for search....and than paste this....   li.NoBullet.jms-bullet>h3>a    ...than let me know with how many it matches.

Comment: Hi sorry just seen your message now. It found 14.

Comment: li:nth-child(1).NoBullet.jms-bullet> h3>a[href^='javascript:ShowSelectedAddInScreen']      ..... i think this also return 14 in ur machine

Comment: That returns 8 not 14

Comment: ok...   span>ul.NoIndent>li.NoBullet.jms-bullet>h3>a[href^='javascript:ShowSelectedAddInScreen']   ...  check this

Comment: and just final thing...... after opening the inspect window, at left corner u will find a small box with arrow .. this is for inspect element... click on it and than click on that element of ur url where u want to click. Than html part of that element is highlighted ... just go there and right click and from there select copy > copy selector ..... than use that selector in ur code as css  and check what happen and also give me that css to me

Comment: So i'm using Chrome, I guess you mean the magnifying glass icon on the top left?  I have two options to copy either copy HTML or copy XPath. . <a href="javascript:ShowSelectedAddInScreen('-1','8142758e-269a-41f0-b551-433e56dd1225','0','false',false,'false',true, 'Submit a Holiday','e1ff7f13-59fe-4bfc-842d-64a33b0dd98f','4c1ea925-69e5-4950-aeae-18e8493fefd1');"><img src="../Style Sheets/images/Holiday114.png" alt="Book a Holiday">Book a Holiday <span class="AddInItemDescription" title="Place a request for a holiday">Place a request for a holiday </span></a>

Comment: If I use firefox with firebug I get more options so I've pasted the CSS below

Comment: html body.CommunityBody form#Form1 div.MainCommunityTable.MobileLayoutBlock div div div.NarrowCommunity span.AddinSpan div.AddIn.atScreens.AddInViewportDESKTOP div#AddInMyQuickLinks.AddInCollapsible.ui-accordion.ui-widget.ui-helper-reset div#ui-accordion-AddInMyQuickLinks-panel-0.AddInMain.ui-accordion-content.ui-helper-reset.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-bottom.ui-accordion-content-active span ul.NoIndent li.NoBullet.jms-bullet h3 a

Comment: Try by using wait before click on that like Thread.sleep(5000).....thats all from my side...  Thanks

Comment: No the wait didn't work. I did manage to click this <a href="javascript:ToolbarNavigate('5dce23c3-e040-4812-88f4-bdae31a382e8');" onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;" class="Communities">HR</a> - which is on the same page

Comment: so I've just realised everything is contained within an iFrame. I take it this might be the reason as to why nothing worked? Do I have to switch to the iframe first?

Comment: in that case, first switch to iframe like this: driver.switchTo().frame("fram name");

Comment: YES! it worked. Turns out it was contained within 2 iFrames...Sorry I should have checked that first. Thanks for your help though, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Your xpath is incorrect, try this (updated after html code was provided):

`driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='AddInMyQuickLinks']/div/span/ul/li[1]/h3/a")).click();`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply but that didn't work. I tried both and it still can't seem to find the element. I thought perhaps it was looking before the page loads so I added in a wait and still didn't work.

Comment: of course it was wrong, you didn't provide whole html code so I only fixed what you tried... according to your updated answer and html code the xpath should be now as it is in answer

Comment: Tried that as well and it didn't work I got  - org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == .//*[@id='AddInMyQuickLinks']/div/span/ul/li[1]/h3/a (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: have you got anything else I could try? Really appreciate the help

Comment: well you obviously have problem with your xpath, even though my answer might not be 100% correct its step forward. I recommend you get firepath plugin for firebug - then you can just right click the button, inspect in firepath and copy the xpath - done.

Comment: Yeah I tried firebug and using the xpath and it still didn't work. Is there any difference in using @Findby rather than driver.findelement?

Answer (score 0):

In some browsers, you can inspect the element by right-click on it, Inspect the element, when you find the correct element in "developer mode" click right-click on it.

Under Copy->Copy XPath.
Gave you the right way to get full path just copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

**To Get The Xpath of any Tag Do Following:**

```
1) right click on Web Page

2)Select Inspect

3)Right click on Tag

4) Go to Copy  

5) Copy Xpath or Full Xpath
```